# Need to do group by in query

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone please help me with this query I need to apply group by `u.a` and `c.d` in this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.a as ID,DECODE(u.b,'ACT','0','1') as STAT,
                c.d AS role,
                NVL(SUBSTR(c.d, 0, INSTR(c.d, '-')-1), c.d) as app,
                SUBSTR(c.d, INSTR(c.d, ':') + 1) AS role 
  FROM dbo.USER u left outer join dbo.CONNECTION c on u.a = c.a
```

Example :

We have two tables `user` and `connection` :

In `user`, data will be :

```
id. Stat. 
a1  1    
a2  0
```

In `connection`, data will be :

```
Id  app.    Role
a1  abc-d.  Read
a3  cde-f.  Write
a1  abc-d   Read
```

So I need to do left outer join based on `id` and then need to aggregate based on two keys i.e `Id` from `user` and `role` from `connection`.

output :

```
ID  stat  APP ROLE
a1   1    abc-d Read
a2   0
```

Comment: You are unlikely to get a proper answer because problem's description is poor and it's difficult to tell what you are **really** asking.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and dample input and expected output.

Comment: did you try `GROUP BY u.a, c.d` ? Also, if you want to group, you must use an aggregate function for the other fields. if you mean that you want to gather the values together : use a `order by` instead

Comment: Hi @sirmyself I tried with aggregate as well but I am not sure how to do it...If you can give example how can I achieve implementing group by in this scenario that will be grateful.

Comment: @rohit could you please first edit your question to make it a little clearer? If I was able to guess to understand what you meant does not mean every one will be able to. In order to make a full and relevent answer, the question first needs to be complete ;). You can begin by giving an example of the data structure you are using and an example of the expected result.

Comment: @Sirmyself I edited the question...I am sorry I am new to this one so that's why not able to elaborate much

Comment: @rohit no problem at all. We encourage asking questions here. We just also encourage posting complete questions that will make the interrogation clear and thus the answer more relevant and useful for future references.

Comment: @rohit could you include a visual representation of the exected result ? I am not sure I actually understand what kind of grouping you want to do

Comment: You have the column alias role in two places if I'm not mistaken. Is role just c.d or is it SUBSTR(c.d, INSTR(c.d, ':') + 1)?

Comment: Hi @Sirmyself I have added the output its just that i am doing left outer join based on id and i need to do group by based on id from user and role from connection...I know group by require aggregate functions but if you can give me some example related to this query only it will help me to achieve output...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.a as ID,DECODE(u.b,'ACT','0','1') as STAT,c.d AS 
role,NVL(SUBSTR(c.d, 0, INSTR(c.d, '-')-1), c.d) as app,SUBSTR(c.d, INSTR(c.d, 
':') + 1) as  role FROM user u ,connection c where u.id=c id group by 
u.a,SUBSTR(c.d, INSTR(c.d, ':') + 1)
```

you cant have column alias name in group by clause